# JSF datatable to Database

Tags: jsf

I am doing the following process...in JSF

1)Getting Input from user through the text boxes.

2)when the user clicks the add button I want to display the entered data in datatable so I used Arraylist for displaying in datatable.and also text box should cleared for next entry.

3)User entered another data and click on add button that data also display in grid.

4)when the user check it and click , the data that displaying in datatable with use of arraylist should save on database table.

**Note**:First three process Done last 4th process is the issue So please help to how to store the data..
Thanks in Advance

My datatable display

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Address Id</f:facet>
    #{add.address_id}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Customer Id</f:facet>
    #{add.customer_id}
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">Country</f:facet>
    #{add.country}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Address1</f:facet>
    #{add.address1}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Address2</f:facet>
    #{add.address2}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Address3</f:facet>
    #{add.address3}
</h:column>
 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Address4</f:facet>
    #{add.address4}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Address2</f:facet>
    #{add.address2}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">City</f:facet>
    #{add.city}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">County</f:facet>
    #{add.county}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">State</f:facet>
    #{add.state}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Province</f:facet>
    #{add.province}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Postal Code</f:facet>
    #{add.postal_code}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Bill To Flag</f:facet>
    #{add.bill_to_flag}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Enabled Flag</f:facet>
    #{add.enabled_flag}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">End Date Active</f:facet>
    #{add.end_date_active}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Last Update Date</f:facet>
    #{add.last_update_date}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Last Updated By</f:facet>
    #{add.last_updated_by}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Province</f:facet>
    #{add.province}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Creation Date</f:facet>
    #{add.creation_date}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Created By</f:facet>
    #{add.created_by}
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Last Update Login</f:facet>
    #{add.last_update_login}
</h:column>
```

Comment: Can you post code of displaying datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need a CRUD page. Checkout the following link

[Generate PrimeFaces Pages from Entity Classes in NetBeans](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbpfcrudgen)

Netbeans prime faces plugin generates CRUD pages from SQL Database using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

To make the things simple, use any of the ORM technologies (Hibernate, JPA, iBatis etc.,), so that each database table record (or row) is identified as an Java object.

1. Bind the object (technically we call entity) attributes to textboxes
2. Add the entity to the entity list that renders the datatable
3. Commit the entity list when user performs aforementioned third action.

Thanks
JK